# Change implement abstract class template with comment block

Tags: c#, visual-studio

There is any way to implement an abstract class, and change the templates of methods with comments? Something like this:

```
public abstract class A {

    /// <template>
    /// return string.Empty;
    /// </template>
    abstract public string getSomething();
}
```

So, when you "implement abstract class" with visual studio you get a method that return an empty string, instead a method throwing a NotImplementedException.

```
public class B : A {

    public string getSomething() {
        return string.Empty;
    }

}
```

I do not want to change the template of the IDE, because not all the methods must return the same

Comment: Not the exact answer, but you can create snippets with the templates you need, instead of letting VS to auto-create the abstract members you can use these templates for implementing them.

Comment: If you want to provide a default implementation, why not just use a `virtual` method instead of an `abstract` one?

Comment: @David thats why there is no implementation of "templates" in comments. I didnt know that virtual exists. Thanks and sorry!

Comment: @Pythonizo: Would be an interesting feature if it does exist (or could exist).  I too have often wanted the default to not throw an exception, especially for `void` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could use virtual methods to allow a default implementation that you can override in derived classes.

```
public abstract class A {
    //virtual provides default implementation
    public virtual string getSomething() {
        return string.Empty;
    }

}

public class B : A {
    //no need to implement getSomething() it will default to base class (string.Empty)
}

public class C : A {
    //we can override the default implementation of getSomething()
    public override string getSomething() {
        return "Not empty!";
    }
}
```